# How to add a new column to dataframe and make that colum the product of division of two other columns?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, beautifulsoup, analytics

```
# So far I have this
# Import scraping modules
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# URL of page
url = 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2020/receiving.htm'

# Open URL and send to BeautifulSoup
html = urlopen(url)
stats_page = BeautifulSoup(html)

# Collect table headers
column_headers = stats_page.findAll('tr')[0]  # find first table row
column_headers = [i.getText() for i in column_headers.findAll('th')]  # collecting text from all table headers

# Collect table rows
rows = stats_page.findAll('tr')[1:]

# Get stats from each row
wr_stats = []
for i in range(len(rows)):
    wr_stats.append([col.getText() for col in rows[i].findAll('td')])  # iterate through each row collect txt

# Create DataFrame from scraped data
data = pd.DataFrame(wr_stats, columns=column_headers[1:])

# Creating new column Targets per game 
 data['TG'] = data['Tgt']/data['G']


print(data.columns)
```

Getting error:TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'
This was the output of the original columns: dex(['Player', 'Tm', 'Age', 'Pos', 'G', 'GS', 'Tgt', 'Rec', 'Ctch%', 'Yds',
'Y/R', 'TD', '1D', 'Lng', 'Y/Tgt', 'R/G', 'Y/G', 'Fmb'],
How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are creating a DataFrame of strings, before division you should convert both columns to numeric values at first:

```
# Creating new column Targets per game
data["TG"] = pd.to_numeric(data["Tgt"]) / pd.to_numeric(data["G"])
```